# How can I use LibLog with a custom Serilog LoggerConfiguration?

Tags: serilog, liblog

The default provider for [Serilog](http://serilog.net/) in [LibLog](https://github.com/damianh/LibLog) is `SerilogLogProvider`. This provider will use the static entry point `Serilog.Log` to log entries.

How can I use a custom Serilog `ILogger` with LibLog? I could write a new log provider for LibLog but want to know if there are other options already available for me.

The reason for this is that I want to use different log configurations for my application and the library with LibLog support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was to write a custom `ILogProvider`:

https://gist.github.com/mgnslndh/ab0c4309269198d2493f7a408b84a33c